# Is this a predictable process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Denote by $t_n= n \Delta t$ a partition of $[0,T]$ and let $a_n \in \mathcal{F}_{t_n}$ be in $L^2(\Omega)$. Is the process $$X(t) = a_0\mathbb{1}_{[0,\Delta t)}+\sum^{N-1}_{n=1}a_{n-1}\mathbb{1}_{[n\Delta t, (n+1)\Delta t)}(t)$$ predictable?

$X(t)$ is right continuous and adapted, I don't see how to show its predictability.

Comment: This process doesn't look like it's even well-defined: both endpoints on that indicator function are closed.  What is $X(n\Delta t)$ or $X((n+1)\Delta t)$?

Comment: I have fixed it now.

Comment: @user6247850 I have edited it further, can you take a look now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a predictable process.  For simplicity, we can consider the process $$X(t) = a1_{[s,T)}(t)$$ with $a \in \mathcal F_u$ for some $u < s$.  The predictable sigma algebra is generated by the continuous and adapted processes, so we will show $X$ is the pointwise limit of such processes.  Let $X^n(t) = a$ for $s \le t \le T - \frac 1n$, $X^n(t) = 0$ for $t < s - \frac 1n$ or $t \ge T$, and linearly interpolate between.  Then $X^n$ is continuous and adapted (as long as $u < s-\frac 1n$) and hence predictable, and converges pointwise to $X$, so $X$ is predictable.